# How safe is custom encryption?

Tags: python, encryption

I took a few weeks in developing two encryption algorithms and no I am not using it to encrypt any sensitive data, I just want to know how secure these algorithms are If they were to be used. (Please look at the code before saying custom encryption is not safe)

**Encryption algorithm one:**

```
import random
def encrypt(plainText, password):
  plaintextList = []
  passwordSeed = ''
  key = 0
  encryptedText = ''
  count = 0
  for i in plainText:
    plaintextList.insert(count, str(ord(i)))
    count += 1
  for i in password:
    passwordSeed += str(ord(i))
  for i in range(10000):
    random.seed(int(passwordSeed) + (i*1000))
    key += random.randint(-1000000000, 1000000000)
  for i in plaintextList:
    encryptedText += str(int(i)*abs(key)) + '.'
  return encryptedText


def decrypt(hashText, password):
  splitHashText = []
  passwordSeed = ''
  key = 0
  decryptedText = ''
  splitHashText = hashText.split('.')
  for i in password:
    passwordSeed += str(ord(i))
  for i in range(10000):
    random.seed(int(passwordSeed) + (i*1000))
    key += random.randint(-1000000000, 1000000000)
  for i in splitHashText:
    if i.isdigit():
      decryptedText += chr(int(int(i)/abs(key)))
  return decryptedText

while 1 == 1:
  if input('Type e then enter to encrypt and d then enter to decrypt: ') == 'e':
    print(encrypt(input('Encrypt: '),input('Password: ')))
  else:
    print(decrypt(input('Decrypt: '),input('Password: ')))
```

**Encryption algorithm two:**

```
def encrypt(plainText):
  plainList = []
  count = 0
  total = 0
  key = ''
  for i in plainText:
    plainList.insert(count,ord(i))
    total += int(ord(i))
    count += 1
  for i in plainList:
    key += str(i/total) + ';'
  return total, key
def decrypt(hashedText, key):
  keys = key.split(';')
  letters = []
  count = 0
  for i in keys:
    if i != '':
      letters.insert(count, chr(int(float(hashedText)*float(i))))
    count += 1
  return ''.join(letters)
while 1 == 1:
  if input('Type e to encrypt and d to decrypt: ') == 'e':
    data = encrypt(input('String to encrypt: '))
    print('Hashed text: '+ str(data[0]) + '   Key: ' + str(data[1]))
  else:
    print(decrypt(input("Hash: "), input("Key: ")))
```

The code can be ran in any python IDE if you want to test it. If this encryption is secure then feel free to use the code.

Comment: If you have to ask, especially here, then "No". Also read about the [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) myth.

Comment: This kind of questions are off-topic in Cryptography.SE,too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because correctness of an algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start with quote from [blog post](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) of [Bruce Schneier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier):

> One of the most singular characteristics of the art of deciphering is the strong conviction possessed by every person, even moderately acquainted with it, that he is able to construct a cipher which nobody else can decipher.

So if you have to ask, then I dare to say it means your knowledge about cryptography is limited and that unfortunately also means that your code is quite faulty from its very beginning, especially looking at it with security in mind.

> just want to know how secure these algorithms are If they were to be used

Quick look at posted code makes me say it is at best as weak as [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). While there's nothing wrong with experimenting and learning (obviously), you should not use your code for anything more serious than that. There are strong cryptographic algorithms designed by experts in the field, proven and **verified** by other experts in the field. There are ready to use implementations of these in variety of forms. Your code looks like attempt to reinvent the wheel while not really knowing how a proper wheels should look like. And one can fall really hard from a bike with square wheels...

To conclude, let me recommend [Code Book by Simon Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Book) - that book shall help you realize how complex field cryptography is and how much to learn is there for you - that book is written for non experts in mind, so you actually should benefit and learn a lot from it. Really recommend read to anyone (to non technical people too).

PS: there's also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

While I myself used to tinker with encryption, eventually you have to ask if you really trust your ideas. The problem lies in,

> Please look at the code before saying custom encryption is not safe

The [burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)) is on you. You must prove that your encryption is safe.

For example, [RSA has such proofs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/rsa-proof-of-correctness/2894).

So no. You encryption is not safe, because you have not proved it. I don't want to discourage you from experimenting though! I had a lot of fun messing with things like that.

Comment: ... and even that just proves that the *algorithm* behind RSA is secure. It doesn't prove that a custom implementation doesn't have problems, so even a custom implementation of RSA is something I'd look on with some skepticism (e.g. it's very easy for a naive implementation to have properties that are exploitable by timing attack).

Comment: ...and even that doesn't prove anything at all about the *security* of RSA. RSA has never been proved secure, or more precisely, breaking RSA has never been proven to be equivalent to factoring a large semiprime, which in turn has never been proven to be in P or NP.

Answer (score 1):

> Please look at the code before saying custom encryption is not safe

Custom encryption is almost never safe; there are good reasons that answer is by far the most common answer that you get to this type of question. Things that look safe often have exploitable properties either in the algorithm, the implementation, or just because they are easy to brute force.

The biggest problem that you really have is that there are very few people qualified in the world to make an assessment of whether a crypto algorithm is actually secure or not, and I suspect those that can don't hang around on SO.